# sending textbox contect to php via js, processing the value and getting a new value back to html page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to process on PHP, HTML input from the user, i want as the user types, on event of onkeyup send it to php and get a value back and post it back to the html.
the problem is that i cant find a way to do it without submitting the form, any advise?
Thank you!

my HTML:

```
<input id="userin" type="text" name="myinput" onkeyup="valfunction()"<br>
<p id="myresult">value after php processing.</p>
```

my JS:

```
function valfunction() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("myresult").innerHTML = 
                this.responseText;
            }
        };
    xhttp.open("GET", "newval.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
    $text=$_POST['mytext'];
        if ($text=='a') $a=1;
        else if ($text=='b') $a=2;
        else if ($text=='c') $a=3;
echo $a;
?>
```

Comment: GET/$_POST Also consider debouncing your calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're sending a GET request but in PHP you're waiting for POST values. 
Then in php now you should use the filter_input method instead of accessing directly the $_POST.
Then, this should work for get:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "newval.php?" + document.querySelector('#userin').value , true);
```

Be careful to escape characters too

Answer (score 0):

You would have to send a POST request, if you are processing the value as POST from the PHP side.

add this code to send POST request

```
//Send the proper header information along with the request
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

and xhttp.post() should be like this

```
xhttp.open("POST", "https://example.com/?foo=bar&tar=1", true);
xhttp.send(params)
```